# Using XML serialization to persist state of an online exam for 500 concurrent objects - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, deserialization

I am working on an online examination system using ASP.NET, C# and MS SQL Server.

Requirements are to make a state persisted examination system where suppose a student is taking an exam of 100 questions, if exam is interrupted at question # 50, student should start the exam again from where he left the exam.

I seek your opinion regarding if XML or JASON serialization is a good option to use for such kind of application considering the fact that it will need to serialize and deserialize the exam object (containing exam item list) with every click on NEXT or BACK button of the exam conduction module.

Number of students can reach upto 500 with 100 questions for each exam. That means serializing and deserializing 500 objects concurrently.

Please share your input if i should go with serialization or suggest some other better mechanism.

Comment: Why not use the SQL server for this? "Simply" save the updated state of the exam in question to the database.

Comment: I would go for a database, a SQLite would even do better and would be much easier to maintain that a bunch of XML files.

Comment: Using database (SQL or SQLite) is a cogent opinion. As a matter of fact, this was the first option to consider. However, if there is any way to compare the performance of these two mechanisms.

It might sound goofy but major reason behind me thiking about serialization is because it can serialize and deserialize the file on the same server but SQL sits on a different server.

I am aware that complexity of the serialization procedure may overcome the same server advantage but I am looking for a tangible reason to choose between these two OR opt for another better option.

Comment: If you really care that much about performance for 500 users then do your own comparison that would make sense in your specific setup. I really doubt other objective recommendations can be given at this point.

Comment: @WiktorZychla. Dear, I appreciate your input. However, purpose of this post is to seek generice opinion of fellow progrmmers who might have worked for a similar problem. 

Definitly, I am gonna do my own comparison but development of an exam conduction module with two different data management mechanisms and perform the load testings requires some time. What i am looking for is some pointers from people who might have faced scenario before i start developing it.

Comment: @Tiyyob: for over 20 years I do online school management systems for living, if that counts as "who have worked for a similar problem". And let me put this straight, if for any reason you're afraid of a SQL database, consider a noSQL database which makes you as close to JSON files as possible, still without all problems with working on files. If this is your first attempt and you have never implemented a system that would store data in files and would give you a chance to solve all the issues, consider this as a definitive pointer - use a database.

Comment: Much appreciated bro. I am gonna use your advice. Many thanks :-)

Comment: @WiktorZychla I need your further advice on this. out of following two options, which one you prefere when i want to save an "Exam Object" that contains a list of "Exam Items" in it.

1: Save Exam object as a binary object in SQL Table. This way, i will just save and read the objects from table against the Exam ID.

2: Make Master and child tables to save the Exam and Exam Items as rows. In this way, i will loop through the Exam Item list to save it and reload it in Exam Item List.

Please share your opinion that what should be the preferred way.

Many Thanks,

Comment: Parent-Child table relation with a foreign key is a way to go. With an ORM (like Entity Framework) your navigation property will auto load dependant entities. (remember EF6 works both in .NET Framework and .NET 6).

Comment: Bro, many thanks for your continuous support. I followed your suggestions to maintain the state of the exam via master-child table (in case of exam interruption or loss of network etc.) and its working pretty fine. 

However, i need your further input regarding maintaining the state of the exam between the post back of pages as the exam object goes back to null during post back and i don't want to read everytime from the database. Hence, I am thinking to save the exam object in either session OR in memory cache via serialization.

What do you advice ??